# nodejs, using 'await' within finis handling

Tags: node.js, async-await, signals

In my [`finis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/finis) callback, I have:

```
finis((code, signal, error) => {
  await myprocess.stop()
  console.log(`finis(${code}, ${signal}, ${error})`)
})
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function
```

So how to do await within [`finis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/finis)' callback?

PS. `finis()`'s callback function will be run just before the node process exits, and I want to gracefully shutdown `myprocess` by `myprocess.stop()` *before* program exist.

Comment: As the error says, `await` can only be used inside a function declared as `async`.  You can declare your callback to be `async` if you want, but it will probably still NOT do what you want.  It won't block your function from returning.  Your function will still return without waiting for `myprocess.stop()` to finish, but it will return a promise.  Also, `await` only does anything useful when you `await` a promise so `myprocess.stop()` would need to return a promise too.

Comment: OK, in other words -- _"it is impossible to do that"_, right? I can accept it, if that's the only option.

Comment: Depends upon exactly what the `that` is that you're trying to do.  You can get it to pause before it runs the `console.log()` statement, but you can't get it to block the calling function.

Comment: _"how to do await within finis' callback?"_

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish?  Are you trying to block the caller of the callback so it won't continue on with it's code until after `myprocess.stop()` is done.  If so, you can't do that with `await`.  If you're just trying to make the `console.log()` run after the promise that `myprocess.stop()` returns resolves, then `await` will do that.

Comment: Yes! & OK, I can accept it. thx!

Comment: Does `myprocess.stop()` return a promise that resolves when the underlying asynchronous operation completes?

Comment: Why don't you answer the question for what you're really trying to accomplish?  We can't help you if you don't.  "await within finish callback" is not entirely clear what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, `finis()`'s callback function will be run just before the node process exits, and I want to gracefully shutdown `myprocess` by `myprocess.stop()` _before_ program exist. I'll get back to you whether `myprocess.stop()` return a promise..

Comment: Well, if you're trying to get `finis` to wait to shut your program down until after `myprocess.stop()` is done, this won't work unless `finis()` is expecting a promise to be returned from the callback and it waits to shut down your program until that promise resolves.  And, of course, `myprocess.stop()` would also have to return a promise that was resolved when its work was done.

Comment: just confirmed, `myprocess.stop()` does return a promise, which suppose to shutdown myprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error can be fixed by declaring your callback to be `async`.

But, it appears that you have bigger issues than that because you want the caller of your callback (the function `finis`) to wait for your asynchronous operation to complete before it does the rest of its work.  `await` inside your callback by itself will not do that.

Here are a few notes about what `await` does:

1. `await` only does anything useful if you `await` a promise.  It has no magic powers to await some mythical asynchronous operation.  It only awaits a promise.  So, in your particular code, `myprocess.stop()` must return a promise that it resolved when the underlying asynchronous operation in `myprocess.stop()` completes for the `await` in `await myprocess.stop()` to do anything useful.
2. `await` only blocks execution within the local `async` function.  The containing function still returns as soon as you hit the first `await`.  So, it won't block the caller at all.
3. An `async` function (that you can use `await` in) returns a promise so the only way the caller of that function (the caller of your callback in your case which is `finis()` would actually wait for your async operation to complete is if it was expecting the callback to return a promise and if it used either `.then()` or `await` on that callback itself.

If you control the code for the `finis()` function, then we could probably help you modify it to do what you want (to look for a returned promise before it shuts things down), but if you don't control that function, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, the `finis()` function is just a normal npm module that I installed, not coded. So I guess `finis` callbacks does not allow me to gracefully shutdown myprocess by myprocess.stop() then. But I do need to re-read your answer again several times tomorrow, as my brain is no longer working tonight. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
finis(async (code, signal, error) => {
  await myprocess.stop()
  console.log(`finis(${code}, ${signal}, ${error})`)
})
```

Comment: The syntax error is only a small piece of what's going on here.  Read the comments to see what the OP is actually trying to do.